# Upgraded to latest Joomla and site changed

Tags: joomla, joomla3.2

Today I checked to upgrade Joomla site. When I did it added the shadow and grey background. It also added the blue box with site title. I deleted this stuff a long time ago but now nomatter how many solutions I looked at nothing changes it. I have no site title anywhere, went through the personal.css file and index.php as well. Nothings getting rid of or changing this. It was not here before. Can anyone help? www.historygraphicdesign.com

Answer (score 0):

If you're referring to the grey box at the bottom of your site, you can remove this by adding the following to your CSS file:

```
#footer-outer {
    display: none;
}
```

Do bare in mind though that you are using a caching plugin  (JCH Optimize) so you may not see your changes until you clear Joomla's cache. which can be done in the backend

Comment: Thanks. Right after I posted I got rid of the box I was talking about and the footer box. Now my heading and body type is white. Ugh. I remember last time I updated changes went back to unchanged. Thank you

Comment: Have you been editing the core css files? This is why you should never do that. You need to  store your changes separately or even better copy the template and use the copy, then carefully review updates to make css changes that make sense for you.